# Diagonal path between tabular cell

Tags: pdftex

I have this:

[image]

```
   \begin{tabular}{ c  c  c  c  c  c  c  c  c  c }
    0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36& \dots \\
    2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 22 & 29 & 37 & \dots& \dots \\
    5 & 8 & 12 & 17 & 23 & 30 & 38 & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    9 & 13 & 18 & 24 & 31 & 39 & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    14 & 19 & 25 & 32 & 40& \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    20 & 26 & 33 & 41& \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    27 & 34 &42 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    35 & 43 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    44& \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots& \dots \\
    \end{tabular}
```

And I'm trying to draw some zig-zag diagonal path between the points, similarly to this:
[image]

How can I achieve something similar in LaTex? (It doesn't have to be exactly like the picture just the same concept)

Comment: is TikZ allowed?

Comment: Yeah I don't mind anything will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was floating into my hard drive, I did not draw it for this question.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[myarrow/.style={red,->,shorten >=0.25cm, shorten <=.25cm}]
   \matrix (m) [draw,matrix of nodes,inner sep=.2cm,ampersand replacement=\&]
   {
    $\sfrac{1}{1}$ \& $\sfrac{1}{2}$ \& $\sfrac{1}{3}$ \& $\sfrac{1}{4}$ \& $...$\\
    $\sfrac{2}{1}$ \& $\sfrac{2}{2}$ \& $\sfrac{2}{3}$ \& $\sfrac{2}{4}$ \& $...$\\
    $\sfrac{3}{1}$ \& $\sfrac{3}{2}$ \& $\sfrac{3}{3}$ \& $\sfrac{3}{3}$ \& $...$\\
    $\sfrac{4}{1}$ \& $\sfrac{4}{2}$ \& $\sfrac{4}{3}$ \& $\sfrac{4}{4}$ \& $...$\\
    $...$\\
   };
   \draw[myarrow] (m-1-1.center)--(m-2-1.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-2-1.center)--(m-1-2.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-1-2.center)--(m-1-3.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-1-3.center)--(m-2-2.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-2-2.center)--(m-3-1.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-3-1.center)--(m-4-1.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-4-1.center)--(m-3-2.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-3-2.center)--(m-2-3.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-2-3.center)--(m-1-4.center);
   \draw[myarrow] (m-1-4.center)--(m-2-4.center);
   \draw[myarrow,-,dotted] (m-2-4.center)--(m-3-3.center);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you can easily change the arrows flow as you wish once you get the matrix naming scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the rules.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
    \sfrac{1}{1} & \sfrac{1}{2} & \sfrac{1}{3} & \sfrac{1}{4} & ...\\
    \sfrac{2}{1} & \sfrac{2}{2} & \sfrac{2}{3} & \sfrac{2}{4} & ...\\
    \sfrac{3}{1} & \sfrac{3}{2} & \sfrac{3}{3} & \sfrac{3}{3} & ...\\
    \sfrac{4}{1} & \sfrac{4}{2} & \sfrac{4}{3} & \sfrac{4}{4} & ...\\
    ...\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->,red]
     \draw (1-1)--(2-1);
     \draw (2-1)--(1-2);
     \draw (1-2)--(1-3);
     \draw (1-3)--(2-2);
     \draw (2-2)--(3-1);
     \draw (3-1)--(4-1);
     \draw (4-1)--(3-2);
     \draw (3-2)--(2-3);
     \draw (2-3)--(1-4);
     \draw (1-4)--(2-4);
     \draw [dotted] (2-4)--(3-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]